# Integrating Velodyne HDL-64E S2 Lidar with ROS2 - Driver does not seem to support it

Tags: ros2, lidar, velodyne, velodyne-driver

I have a problem that I have been working on for many weeks now: I want to get a Velodyne HDL-64E S2 Lidar running in ROS2.

Background: I am using ROS2 Humble under Ubuntu 22.04 and have connected the lidar via LAN. I can also see and use it in Veloview.
I use the ros-driver for velodyne from Github. The build etc all works but although the sensor should be supported I have to create the launch file myself.

The driver on Github: https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne

But I get the following error:

> [velodyne_transform_node-2] [WARN] [1705164833.369225252]
> [velodyne_pointcloud]: Timings not supported for model 64E_S2
> [velodyne_transform_node-2] [WARN] [1705164833.369231383]
> [velodyne_pointcloud]: NO TIMING OFFSETS CALCULATED. ARE YOU USING A
> SUPPORTED VELODYNE SENSOR?

I also find the cause of the error in the velodyne pointcloud or in rawdata.cc, the sensor cannot be handled at all as I understand it. However, the driver was written especially for HDL 64 and only adapted for newer ones, so it should work.
I have also tried older ROS versions with old driver versions but nothing works.

I am now really desperate and have searched the entire internet, github, this forum etc... I would be very happy about any suggestions. Maybe someone is familiar with it or could take a quick look at it.

Many thanks in advance.

The launch file:

```py
"""Launch the velodyne driver, pointcloud, and laserscan nodes with default configuration."""

import os
import yaml

import ament_index_python.packages
import launch
import launch_ros.actions


def generate_launch_description():
    driver_share_dir = ament_index_python.packages.get_package_share_directory('velodyne_driver')
    driver_params_file = os.path.join(driver_share_dir, 'config', 'HDL64E-S2_Leonie.yaml')
    velodyne_driver_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(package='velodyne_driver',
                                                   executable='velodyne_driver_node',
                                                   output='both',
                                                   parameters=[driver_params_file])

    convert_share_dir = ament_index_python.packages.get_package_share_directory('velodyne_pointcloud')
    convert_params_file = os.path.join(convert_share_dir, 'config', 'HDL64E-S2_Leonie-params.yaml')
    with open(convert_params_file, 'r') as f:
        convert_params = yaml.safe_load(f)['velodyne_transform_node']['ros__parameters']
    convert_params['calibration'] = os.path.join(convert_share_dir, 'params', 'HDL64E-S2_Leonie.yaml')
    velodyne_transform_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(package='velodyne_pointcloud',
                                                      executable='velodyne_transform_node',
                                                      output='both',
                                                      parameters=[convert_params])



    return launch.LaunchDescription([velodyne_driver_node,
                                     velodyne_transform_node,
                                     
                                     launch.actions.RegisterEventHandler(
                                         event_handler=launch.event_handlers.OnProcessExit(
                                             target_action=velodyne_driver_node,
                                             on_exit=[launch.actions.EmitEvent(
                                                 event=launch.events.Shutdown())],
                                         )),
                                     ])
    print(foo)
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to link to the relevant resources you're referring to. Especially the drivers that you're trying to use? And it would likely help if you shared the launch file that you created.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes of course, I added it now.